# How to publish React Component that is a class to NPM without having uglify.js issues?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, uglifyjs

I rewrote ES5 package to modern syntax to avoid deprecation warnings and published it to npm.

Most React projects, including ones based on `next.js` and `create-react-app` use uglify.js and they break at `class` keyword.

```
{ Error: commons.js from UglifyJs
Unexpected token: name
...
```

How do I properly write React component that uses class and works with uglify.js and npm?

Comment: Classes are a feature that is not parsed by UglifyJS, so you will need a transpiler (like Babel) somewhere down the road. Either your NPM package should provide a transpiled version of your module or your React project should transpile your module (less standard)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`React.createClass` has been deprecated because it's going to be removed from the main `react` package in an upcoming version, but [you can still use the now-separate `create-react-class` package instead](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-without-es6.html) if you still need/want to write components using it without getting deprecation warnings.

---

If you're using ES6 classes to write components which will be published to npm, you will need to add a transpile step so you're publishing ES5 code to npm for the forseeable future because - as you've seen - tools which don't support ES6 will break on them, and apps which use them will break in browsers which don't support ES6 classes natively (e.g. IE11).

If you already have Babel set up to transpile JSX, transpiling classes away before publishing isn't much extra work - install the `babel-preset-es2015` preset and add it to your Babel config.

---

Even when we reach the point where ES6 support in tools and browsers is no longer an issue, standard ES6 classes aren't a very convenient way to write React components compared to `createClass`, as they introduce `constructor` boilerplate, need manual method binding and having to declare static properties such as `propTypes` separately.

It's common to use experimental implementations of proposed language features (`babel-preset-stage-2` covers the most useful ones) for those convenience features to overcome this (even the documentation above about writing React components without ES6 has an example of this) and transpile them away with Babel plugins, so if you use these features you will have to keep transpiling your code anyway!